# Unknown token in SQL select where statement

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, firebird

I have three tables:

1. PRESS Table : ID, NAME
2. REGIONS Table : ID, NAME

Each "Press" is published in certain areas (Regions), so I created a child table called "PRESSREGIONS" :

3. PRESSREGIONS : ID, NAME, IDPRESS

When trying to select records from PRESSREGIONS related to the current PRESS, I use:

```
SELECT * FROM PRESSREGION WHERE PRESSREGION.IDPRESS = PRESS.ID
```

I have the following error:

> ERROR -206 TOKEN UNKNOWN PRESS.ID

I even tried with another table and another field just to try and got the same error. Is there anything wrong with my statement?

Delphi RIO 10.3 - Firedac - Firebird 3.0

Comment: What shall that _current PRESS_ be as seen from the server?

Comment: There is no reference to `PRESS` anywhere in the statement, so Firebird doesn't know what you mean with `PRESS`. However, your query would produce a _"Column unknown"_ error, so you are not providing a [mre]. Please update your question with all relevant information to reproduce this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel his list says `PRESSREGIONS` but his query says `PRESSREGION` in singular. Whioch however still effects in different error: Table Unknown - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=1c5f17a6f390abb6dd9e8b81012c77f2

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` with `PRESS`.

```
SELECT
    pr.*,
    p.*
FROM
    PRESSREGION AS pr
    INNER JOIN PRESS AS p ON pr.IDPRESS = p.ID
```

Comment: Although that may or may not be what the OP wants, the query in the question would produce a different error in Firebird (_"Column unknown"_), so there is something else going on

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `PRESS.id` because you did not declared `PRESS` as something you are going to use.

"Translating" to Delphi your queries would look like having two files:

```
Unit A;
inteface
  var AAA: integer;
implementation
end.
```

and then

```
Program B;
begin
  AAA := 10;
end.
```

Trying to compile the program - you would receive just the same error, variable AAA was not defined, the token AAA is not known to the Delphi compiler when compiling the module B. Until you either explicitly declare B-local variable AAA or explicitly declare your intention to import AAA variable from the unit A of all existing units (`Program B; uses A; ...`) - the program would not compile.

If the compiler can not know with absolute warranty what you intended to do - it can not do guesswork and write the program for you by somewhat random estimations.

Same with SQL, unless you **explicitly declare** the table PRESS (maybe with a shortcut/alias) as something you do have intent to use - the query compiler would not know.

Read chapter chapter [6.1.3. The FROM clause](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-from) from Firebird documentation.
Or Martin Gruber's "Essential SQL".
Or there were good beginners books for Delphi 3 and Delphi 5 in Russian and probably in other languages too. Actually, "vast and generic scope, shallow depth" beginners books about SQL databases might do better service to you as of yet, than very detailed "narrow scope in-depth" kinds of documentation.

On option to explicitly declare that would be, in SQL'89 flavor "implicit join" way

```
   SELECT * FROM PRESSREGIONs, Press WHERE PRESSREGIONs.IDPRESS = PRESS.ID
```

Another option, quoted above by Dai, using SQL'92 "explicit join" flavor would be

```
   SELECT * FROM PRESSREGIONs JOIN Press ON PRESSREGIONs.IDPRESS = PRESS.ID
```

See more SQL commands and Firebird's reactions to them at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=8f32007629284cf0aa30128d5a7b5e10